# Puppet problem with sysctl

Tags: centos, sysctl

Running CentOS 5.5 with Puppet 0.25.5

I have installed and am using the [puppet-sysctl module](https://github.com/gnuine/puppet-sysctl).

However the following error occurs:

```
//linux_tuning/Sysctl::Value[net.core.rmem_default] Sysctl[net.core.rmem_default] (err): Failed to retrieve current state of resource: No ability to determine if sysctl exists
//linux_tuning/Sysctl::Value[net.core.rmem_default]/Exec[exec_sysctl_net.core.rmem_default] (notice): Dependency sysctl[net.core.rmem_default] has 1 failures
//linux_tuning/Sysctl::Value[net.core.rmem_default]/Exec[exec_sysctl_net.core.rmem_default] (warning): Skipping because of failed dependencies
```

sysctl is installed. And /etc/sysctl.conf is present.

Anyone have an idea as to why this is happening and have an idea as to how to fix it?

An excerpt from puppet.conf:

```
[main]
    vardir = /var/lib/puppet
    logdir = /var/log/puppet
    rundir = /var/run/puppet
    ssldir = $vardir/ssl
    runinterval = 21600
```

Comment: Can you post your puppet.conf?

Comment: @Kowh Any part in particular or just the whole thing?

Comment: The [main] section in particular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to [enable pluginsync](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/plugins_in_modules.html#enabling-pluginsync):

In puppet.conf:

```
[main]
pluginsync = true
```

Comment: This is set under `[puppetd]`, should it be under `[main]` as well?

Comment: Might as well move it. Putting it under `[main]` causes it to apply to all puppet executables, making the other entry redundant.

Comment: This module is poorly documented. I've been trying to figure out how to integrate it into my install.